# Java multithreading - schedule a task everytime the task finishes its job

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to run a task that will contain a Timer in it that does another task. I need to wait till that sub-task is done executing before i can run another "parent task".

So how can i make the main task wait till its sub tasks are finished executing before shooting another task?

I thought of notifying it with boolean isDone in each task but im not sure if its proper

Comment: Please provide code example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you `submit` Tasks, you will be provided a `Future` which you can put into a List. You can then call `get()` on each which will return when they are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) in the parent thread which will wait until the child finishes it's work and calls the countDown() method so that the parent thread may continue it's work. You can have multiple children and you can adjust the CountDownLatch's count value to be equal to them.

I wouldn't recomend using a volatile variable since you will have to continuosly put the parent thread to sleep and check if the variable has changed after it wakes up.

Answer (score 0):

To wait for a bunch of tasks to finish: [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-)

```
// Assume we have an ExecutorService "pool" and tl is list of tasks
List<Future<SomeType>> results = pool.invokeAll( tl ); // will block until all tasks in tl are completed
```

Or

```
// Assume we have an ExecutorService "pool" and N is the count of tasks
List<Future<SomeType>> batch = new ArrayList<>(N);

for( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ){ 
     batch.add(pool.submit(new Task(i)));
}

for( Future fut : batch ) fut.get();
/* get will block until the task is done. 
 * If it is already done it will return immediately.
 * So if all futures in the list return from get, all tasks are done.
 */
```